# How Linux implement the 'queue spin lock'?

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock

According to the article http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=queue-spinlocks-linux-4.2, since version 4.2, Linux kernel would have queue spin locks. But in version 4.4, I went through the implementation of `spin_lock` and found that they implement the spin-lock like this in `kernel/locking/spinlock.c`:

```
void __lockfunc __raw_##op##_lock(locktype##_t *lock)           \
{                                   \
    for (;;) {                          \
        preempt_disable();                  \
        if (likely(do_raw_##op##_trylock(lock)))        \
            break;                      \
        preempt_enable();                   \
                                \
        if (!(lock)->break_lock)                \
            (lock)->break_lock = 1;             \
        while (!raw_##op##_can_lock(lock) && (lock)->break_lock)\
            arch_##op##_relax(&lock->raw_lock);     \
    }                               \
    (lock)->break_lock = 0;                     \
}                                   \
```

And there is a `cmpxchg` in `do_raw_spin_trylock`, so basically it just a TATAS spin-lock.

However, when I digging deeper, I find `do_raw_spin_lock` will goes into a function `queued_spin_trylock` and the type of `lock` variable become `qspinlock`. So where is the queue spin? Is it hiding in somewhere or just waiting for the future implementation?

For searching the identifiers in the source code, here is the tool: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're looking at is in the #else case of this:

```
#if !defined(CONFIG_GENERIC_LOCKBREAK) || defined(CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC)
/*
 * The __lock_function inlines are taken from
 * include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h
 */
#else
...
```

By default, on x86, CONFIG_GENERIC_LOCKBREAK is not defined, so the compiler won't compile that code (i.e. in the `#else` clause). There are lots of potential paths through the maze of locking `ifdef`s. The exact path taken will depend on your architecture and any custom selections you've made in your `.config`.

Comment: I know, but in another definition, `__raw_spin_lock` calls `do_raw_spin_lock`, it is basically the same behavior, right? I still don't see where the queue is.

Comment: Look at `do_raw_spin_lock` in `include/linux/spinlock.h`. That calls `arch_spin_lock`, one implementation of which is in `include/asm-generic/qspinlock.h`

Comment: OK, I got it. I don't know why LXR did not regard the `do_raw_spin_lock` here as a definition, that's why I missed it... Thanks a lot!